# Mariadb Error : Mysql server has gone away [import dump]

Tags: mysql, windows, mariadb, mariadb-connect-engine

I am importing dump file in mariadb on windows . It show me "Mysql server has gone away" error . I knew the solution that add

max_allowed_packet=500M

in my.cnf but issue is that is have seen five init files in that directory

C:\Program Files\MariaDB 5.5

1. my-huge.ini
2. my-innodb-heavy-4G.ini
3. my-large.ini
4. my-medium.ini
5. my-small.ini

so in which file i change  "max_allowed_packet=500M" .Please suggest to me how i change the configuration of mariadb on windows for this issue.

Comment: You can check the datadir with the following query: `select @@datadir`

Answer (score 2):

I have face same problem because configuration file did not work for me,so you have to pass max_allowed_packet value directly in a query.

mysql  -u username -p --max_allowed_packet=1073741824  < dump.sql

Answer (score 0):

None of these .ini files are used by your server, with default installation. Those are examples.

my.ini in the data directory is used, which in default installation is in
C:\Program Files\MariaDB 5.5\data